# Failure to upgrade or update

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates

Could someone help me know what is wrong with my laptop? I failed to update or upgrade with my terminal or update manager. The system in terminal returns an error of unable to fetch some archives after trying to upgrade.

Comment: What error? Can you check connectivity? Are you using a proxy, for example?

Comment: "Unable to fetch some archives" is the error. I have a good wired connection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists) Reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/798515/failure-to-upgrade-or-update/798563#798563

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my problem. I had to untick one of the software sources from my update manager settings. That was after reading about the causes of the error I received. My system was then able to update and is now running fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to update/upgrade your system at the end of the console output you can view the package name which were unable to update/upgrade.

Note the package name and go to

> /etc/apt/

Inside the directory you will find sources.d directory, go inside the directory and look for the files referring to those packages which were mentioned in the error messages. Remove those files and it should work.